# Perl equivalent of java Iterator

Tags: perl, perl-module

In java for a class that represents a collection, if it implements the iterable interface, iterating over the collection can be done without any knowledge about the collection using the foreach loop.

Can we do something similar in perl? Suppose my perl class is a collection. What is the best way of iterating over the collection ?

Comment: Hint: Java got the idea for its `foreach` keyword from Perl.

Comment: @mob: But Java Collections con't have a `foreach` method. All they have is `iterator`.

Comment: The nearest thing to a Java collection is a Perl hash, although you could implement pretty much anything you want if you wrote a class. Do you need the same interface as Java, i.e. with `next`, `hasNext` and `remove`? You can iterate over Perl hashes using `each`, but you can have only one iterator per hash.

Comment: @Borodin, Java has had [Perl-style for-each loops](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) since 1.5. I did mispeak, though. They are called "For-Each" loops but they just overload the `for` keyword.

Comment: @mob: Sure, I agree, but it's unrelated to the question which involves Collection objects that you can't `foreach` over.

Comment: @mob: Of course, in Perl, `for` and `foreach` are just alternate spellings of the same keyword, too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perl's two builtin collections — arrays and hashes — have various ways to be iterated:

1. `foreach` loops: This loops (but not iterates lazily) through each item in the given list. Using this on hashes is probably wrong, you should either iterate over the `values` or the `keys`:

   ```
   foreach my $key (keys %hash) {
     do something;
   }
   ```
2. The `each` iterator: You can iterate through "collections" with the `each` function. Each time it is called, it will return a list of a key/index, and a value. If no further items are there, it will return a false value:

   ```
   while (my ($key, $value) = each %hash) {
     do something;
   }
   ```

   You can only have one such iterator per array/hash. This usage of `each` on arrays is a rather new feature.
3. The `each` idiom can be extended via closures to create custom iterators:

   ```
   my %hash = ...;
   my @keys = keys %hash; # cache the current keys
   my $i = 0;
   my $iter = sub {
     return unless $i < @keys;
     my $key = $keys[$i++];
     return ($key, $hash{$key});
   };
   ...;
   while (my ($key, $value) = $iter->()) {
     do something;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

If you use a Perl hash in place of a Collection, then you can use [`each`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html) to iterate over it.

Every call to `each %hash` will return the next key/value pair, or an empty list at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Perl doesn't have Java-style iterators, cause it doesn't need them.  Perl has rather robust hashes and lists built in, which supplant most custom collections you'll ever need, and you can easily loop over them already.  And if you want to do something with each element (and particularly if you want to build a list of the results), there's functions like `map` that you can pass a code ref to.

If you really want this Java'ism, though, you could build your own iterator class.  It doesn't have to implement or extend any particular interface, cause Perl duck-types -- and normal people don't use iterators anyway, so there's no standard interface in the first place.  And it doesn't have anything to do with `foreach`.  :P

Really, it's better to just use the standard collection types.  I've never run into a case where i needed a custom collection.

Answer (score 1):

You can create arbitrarily complex iterators in perl by using closures and functional programming techniques, for when you need something above and beyond perl's built in ability to iterate over arrays and hashes.  Here is is simplistic example to illustrate the technique - in this instance, its pretty useless since an iterator is unnecessary for this particular case.  But as I said this technique can be applied usefully in other scenarios.  This example will walk over an array backwards, skipping elements that we want excluded (in this case, the letter 'c').

```
sub gen_iter {
    my @collection = @_;
    return sub {
        while (my $item = pop @collection) {
            next if $item eq 'c';
            return $item;
        }
    }
}

my $it = gen_iter((qw/a b c d e f g/));

# prints 'gfedba'
while (my $item = $it->()) {
    print $item;
}
```

I recommend grabbing the free ebook 'High-Order Perl' and digesting the chapter on iterators.  It has some great, useful examples.